# OData filtering before selecting inside an expand query

Tags: rest, dynamics-crm, odata, query-string, odata-v4

I am writing a query for metadata in Dynamics 365, but I think this problem could be universal for any OData query.

My problem is as follow:

In Dynamics, we can have multiple types of fields in entities, such as strings, bools or lookup. I want to write a query that returns the type of entity the lookup is addressing.

```
{url}/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='Account')
?$select=
    LogicalName
&$expand=
    Attributes(
        $select=
            LogicalName,
            AttributeType,
            Targets; -- Problematic property
        $filter=
      AttributeType+eq+Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeTypeCode'Lookup')
```

If I dont include the select for Targets in this query, I get the correct result, being all attributes where theyr AttributeType is Lookup.

But when I require the Targets to be aslo included, I get an error message

```
Could not find a property named 'Targets' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata
```

Because the Target property only exists on those arrribute that are of the type Lookup, therefore selecting this column from a string attribute will fail and throw this error.

Is there a way to first filter to lookups before selecting a column? I have found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541392.aspx) that the order of evaluation is

**$filter, $inlinecount, $orderby, $skiptoken, $skip, $top, $expand, $select, $format**

which is exactly what I need, except I don't think this order is the same when invoked inside the $expand attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the lookup entities you might have better luck doing an `$expand` on `ManyToOneRelationships` instead of `Attributes` and getting the `ReferencedEntity` value.

[image: ManyToOne]

Something like this should work:
`.../api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')
?$select=LogicalName
&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity)`

Subset of results:

> {"@odata.context":"https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#EntityDefinitions(LogicalName,ManyToOneRelationships(ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity))/$entity","LogicalName":"account","MetadataId":"70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84","ManyToOneRelationships":[{"ReferencingAttribute":"msdyn_accountkpiid","ReferencedEntity":"msdyn_accountkpiitem","MetadataId":"2a712c96-09b1-e811-a842-000d3a33bdbd"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"preferredequipmentid","ReferencedEntity":"equipment","MetadataId":"b4b462b5-ee78-467d-a97a-45264d234816"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"primarycontactid","ReferencedEntity":"contact","MetadataId":"410707b1-9554-4cd9-8437-6608b1802904"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"masterid","ReferencedEntity":"account","MetadataId":"51fa4af7-93d0-4f06-8949-38a0036ddc64"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"preferredsystemuserid","ReferencedEntity":"systemuser","MetadataId":"a6b48e23-fada-4b7f-8655-530bba050765"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"createdbyexternalparty","ReferencedEntity":"externalparty","MetadataId":"9967fe7d-84ee-4a26-9ad7-a8fdbdfa2316"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"modifiedby","ReferencedEntity":"systemuser","MetadataId":"8be02a9d-0776-4c76-b35f-1c92dd791d9e"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"parentaccountid","ReferencedEntity":"account","MetadataId":"57511732-b553-4cfb-bcf2-d280f9f8c6f1"},{"ReferencingAttribute":"entityimageid","ReferencedEntity":"imagedescriptor","MetadataId":"5b4942d5-1fcd-49ca-91c0-2737f5f104f3"},

Also, for reference, I tried doing an `$expand` on Attributes AND Targets:
`../api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=Attributes($filter=AttributeType+eq+Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeTypeCode%27Lookup%27&$expand=Targets)`

It throws an error:

> "Query option '$expand' was specified more than once, but it must be
>   specified at most once."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The expand of metadata helps a lot. I have tried to call the metadata endpoint specifically but it didn't occur to me that you can expand the relationship instead of attributes. This query did the trick.   


Also for reference: I am writing something that gets all the data that the program will need to map, meaning downloading values from lookups of lookups. I had to implement logic to split this into multiple calls, specifically because Dynamics is limited to one expand call at the time

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to expand Attributes and ManyToOneRelationships in the same call if you separate them by a comma.

```
GET https://{{baseUrl}}/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')?$select=LogicalName,EntitySetName&$expand=Attributes($select=LogicalName),ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity)
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Single request to get everything needed.